# How to create single json object from three different json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to create single JSON object from three different JSON object e.g.

Three variable containing JSON value :

**1. GTX_INNER_JOIN
2. GTX_LEFT_OUTER_JOIN
3. GTX_RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN**

all of them have same (key,value) pair. I want single JSON containing value from all of them.

I have tried angularJS and tried **Angular: Copy , Extend and Merge** but i didnt get the result as i want .

```
    var vGreenTXJSON = {};
    angular.extend(vGreenTXJSON ,vGreenTxData.GTX_INNER_JOIN );
    angular.extend(vGreenTXJSON ,vGreenTxData.GTX_LEFT_OUTER_JOIN );
    angular.extend(vGreenTXJSON ,vGreenTxData.GTX_RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN );
```

I want single JSON e.g.

[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}‌​,{},{},{},...]

like this , but this is creating array of JSON like :

object :

[GTX_INNER_JOIN :[{},{},{},{},{},....],

GTX_LEFT_OUTER_JOIN:[{},{},{},{},{},.‌​...],

GTX_RIGHT_OUTER‌​_JOIN:[{},{},{},{},{‌​},....]]

Answer (score 0):

it can be very helpful to specify the result you're expecting. you can do -

```
var vGreenTXJSON = {
    innerJoin: vGreenTxData.GTX_INNER_JOIN,
    leftOuterJoin: vGreenTxData.GTX_LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,
    rightOuterJoin: vGreenTxData.GTX_RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN
};
```

Comment: Its creating array of JSON i want single JSON

Answer (score 0):

If you directly copy all properties of `vGreenTxData` to `vGreenTXJSON`, you could use below.

```
angular.extend(vGreenTXJSON ,vGreenTxData);
```

If you want to specifically grab some of Props from `vGreenTxData` object then it would be look like below.

```
angular.extend(vGreenTXJSON ,{
    GTX_InnerJoin: vGreenTxData.GTX_INNER_JOIN,
    GTX_OuterJoin: vGreenTxData.GTX_LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,
    GTX_Right_OuterJoin: vGreenTxData.GTX_RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN
});
```

Comment: Its creating array of JSON i want single JSON

Comment: @Shantnu what do you mean by that? Would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: I want single JSON e.g. [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},...] like this , but this is creating array of JSON like : object :[GTX_INNER_JOIN :[{},{},{},{},{},....],GTX_LEFT_OUTER_JOIN:[{},{},{},{},{},....],GTX_RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN:[{},{},{},{},{},....]]

Comment: @Shantnu Sorry, still it isn't clear, can you please udpate your question with more details like expect output with initial values.